# Product flavors, how to use custom class

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I found this [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html) but I have doubts.
I have some doubts about Product flavors in android studio. I have a structure something like this:

app > src > main > java > com > mycompany > product > packages(view/ utils/ etc)

```
      > app2 > java > com > mycompany > product > packages(view/ utils/ etc)

      > app3 > java > com > mycompany > product > packages(view/ utils/ etc)
```

1. How can I use a `class` in the `main` pack but with changes of code snippets for a specific build? I know there is the possibility of using a `buildConfigField` with a flag for use `if` and use code snippets in a class, but I think it bad and was wondering if you can use the same class or other means to use these snippets of code. I tried to create the same package structure and create a personalized copy of the class, but Android Studio complains of double class, something that does not occur with the `res` files.
2. How can I generate apks in `debug` and simultaneous `release` for each build.
3. How do simultaneous tests for each build.

Comment: This is really 3 or 4 questions in one. You should really consider limiting the scope of your question to just one of these.

Answer (score 1):

Say, you have `main` and 2 flavors '`free`' and '`paid`'

1) You either have a file `MyFile.java` in src/main and then it goes to both flavors

Or you have `src/free/MyFile.java` and `src/paid/MyFile.java` then the files will be different per flavors

Or you have `src/free/MyFile.java and` no such file in `src/paid` then `MyFile.java` will only be used by 'free' flavor

(**Edited**: this last case will only compile if `MyFile.java` is not referred by anything in the `src/main`)

2) Use gradlew `assembleDebug` to generate all flavors for a debug build or gradlew `assembleFreeDebug` or gradlew `assemblePaidDebug` to generate only free or paid flavor. Same for release.

3) Same as 2) I don't remember target names

Android Studio has '`Build Variants`' window in which you can take care of 2) and 3)

Comment: "Or you have src/free/MyFile.java and no such file in src/paid then MyFile.java will only be used by 'free' flavor" -- that will fail to compile in most cases. If `main` code refers to `MyFile`, there has to exist a `MyFile` in every flavor.

Comment: Ah, indeed! In my code it was only referred from the flavor itself.

Comment: The project was initially developed in the main. And this class X would customizes it to flavor A. When trying to refactor the class X to flavor the A and B flavor, Android Studio accuses error not find the reference of class X in other classes within the main.